# Functional way to call method on objects in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I would like to call a method which takes no arguments and returns nothing, on each Object in an Array of homogenous objects, without using a for loop like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].someMethod();
}
```

I've looked at using `Array.forEach` (and discounted `Array.map`), tried passing the method name as a string, and by using `call` and grabbing the prototype method from one of the objects, as well as reading around the area on various websites.

I don't see a clean way to do it, such that every invocation is bound to the correct `this`. Can someone point out what blindingly obvious technique I've overlooked?

Comment: Use an anonymous function as the callback of the `forEach`, and call the method as usual: `list.forEach(function(o) {  o.someMethod(); });`

Comment: you need a prototype or method for each of `list[i]`.

Comment: if you want to control which this is passed to the function you can use `list[i].someMethod.apply(contextThis);`

Comment: please add `list`.

Comment: @OriDrori yeah, that's blindingly obvious and I missed it :) thanks. please post as actual answer and I will accept

Comment: @NicholasShanks - welcome. It's a slight oversight. No need for an answer.

Comment: "I would like to call a method which takes no arguments and returns nothing" This does not sound like the "Functional way" to me. If nothing is returned and nothing is passed, it can't really be a pure function without side effects. Maybe you can explain what `someMethod` does, or, alternatively, what you think is wrong with using the `for` loop.

Comment: @user3297291 Yes, I realise it is a pure side-effect I am invoking—it was mostly the technique evading my sight that rilled me. And there is nothing 'wrong' _per se_ with a for loop in this context, I am just re-writing some code as a learning exercise. In this particular instance I have an auto-complete suggestion list, and when a response comes back I want to cancel any outstanding earlier autocomplete requests (using `jqxhr.abort()`) so that "sta" suggestions do not replace "stac" suggestions if the latter arrived first.

Comment: @NicholasShanks “a pure side effect”, what?  Anyway the rest of your comment describes your real question. Look up a technique coined [*debouncing*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Debouncing). There’s countless libraries and tutorials to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use an anonymous function as the callback of the `forEach`, and call the method as usual: `list.forEach(function(o) { o.someMethod(); });`